# LDAP filter to only allow users that have a group membership

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Is there a filter in LDAP that would let me filter out users that don't have a groupMembership?  I can find information on filtering by group, but I'd like to say "if a user is not in any groups, then don't include them".

Comment: visit https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEV/How+to+write+LDAP+search+filters

Comment: Which LDAP server are you using?  A user that is a member of ANY group or a specific Group?

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like: `(&(objectClass=person)(!(groupMembership=*)))`. That just asks for all users where groupMembership is not present. Assuming `groupMembership` is a backlinked attribute on the user.

Comment: You mean the `groupMembership` attribute? Yeah, I was unsure as to what kind of LDAP they're using.

Answer (score 0):

Not all directories store a static attribute on the user for each group they are a member of.

eDirectory for example stores Member on the Group, listing the users who are members.  It stores GroupMembership on the user, listing all the groups the user is a member of.

Active Directory on the other hand stores Member on the Group but does not statically store the group membership data on the User.  Rather it defines a dynamic attribute on the user, called MemberOf, that is evaluated, each time you query for the attribute.

That is, when you ask AD for the value of that attribute, it does an LDAP query in the background that is functionally something like `(&(objectClass=Group)(Member=cn=MyUser,ou=MyOU,dc=domain,dc-local))`

Thus the attribute is MemberOf, but I am not certain that a query for `(!(memberOf=*))` would work, since that implies doing that implicit query on every object, which could be painful.